# C# Abrindo Arquivos

Tags: c#, arquivo

Gostaria de saber como fazer para abrir um arquivo em seu programa nativo com `C#`.

> Exemplo:
>   Eu tenho um arquivo `.xls` (planilha).
>   Quando eu quiser abrir ela,
>   meu sistema faz um request e abre ela no excel.

Desde já agradeço

Comment: Poderia melhorar um pouco sua pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Use a classe [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myFile.xls");
```